# html5 validation required setCustomValidity

Tags: html

i have validation function for check user input info.
if user input empty in text, it will pup message  ' Please enter Number'.

now, I also want to add error message if user input more than 7 numbers, it will show error message , But i dont have any idea for two error message when user input wrong data .

i try to use type="Number" maxLength = "7", but it is not work because type number cannot support maxLength.

Anybody can help? thanks

```html
<input asp-for="ID" id="ID" class="form-control" type="text" value="@Context.Request.Query["ID"]" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(' Please enter Number')"
  oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"   />
```

Comment: You may need to customize your setCustomValidity Method even further with an addEventListerner, have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Implementing_a_customized_error_message
if this is what you need, please tell me, I will write a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

- `max` is what you are looking for, not `maxlength`:

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
<span>Try submitting with number <code>1111111</code>.</span>
<input type="number" max="7" required="required" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

- **Brute force method**: Use JavaScript to see if the number is greater than 7:

```js
function check(object) {
  console.log(object.value);
  if (object.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Please enter something!</span>';
  } else if (parseInt(object.value) > 7) {
    document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red;">Number exceedes 7!</span>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('err').innerHTML = '<span style="color:#00ff00;">Good to go!</span>';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" onkeyup="check(this);" />
<span id="err"></span>
```

And also, maxlength refers to the **maximum characters** that can be entered into the text field. So `maxlength="7"` will allow `1111111` to be entered.